# Teardown test data using Apache Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-redshift

I am building an ETL process using PySpark which is on Python 3, Apache Spark 2 and Fedora 20.

I am also building automated tests against the framework but am struggling with the tear down of data at the end of the tests.

I can set up specific data in an AWS Redshift cluster using Spark but, short of wiping out all data in a table, don't seem to be able to delete specific data.

If I try and run a DELETE FROM...WHERE... I get a command not allowed error.
It isn't a permissions issue as the exact command runs for the exact same user in our DB IDE (Aquafold data studio 17).

Short of installing something like psycopg2 or pyodbc (which feels like overkill) I am not sure how to achieve the equivalent DELETE with a WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AWS Redshift driver has a number of options and amongst these are two in particular

- preations
- postactions

These can contain SQL statement(s) to be executed on AWS Redshift.

Where there are multiple statements they must be separated by a semi-colon character.

**DO NOT** terminate the final statement with a semi-colon as the driver thinks that there is a subsequent query and fails.

When either preactions or postactions are mentioned in the options then they must contain valid SQL, they cannot be blank.  A simple SELECT 1 will suffice.

Note that there is a further option that it is advisable to use.

```
"extracopyoptions="ACCEPTINVCHARS ' '"
```

AWS Redshift does not support NVARCHAR characters and treats NVARCHAR as a synonym for VARCHAR.  The option above recodes any characters not understood by RedShift as an empty space.